# setting readable permission to root folder (/) to execute listFiles()

Tags: android

I am attempting to add root browser to my file management app. I have rooted my device and mounted file system (/) on rw. But I am not able to list files through listFiles method on root (/) so as to populate the contents of files. It is observed canRead method returns false. So, it seems necessary to set the file to readable to true. I tried with setReadable(true), but to no avail. Setting setReadable(true) still returned false even after changing the 'other' permission to 'rwx' to root folder.

I could execute ls -l to list the sub files under root through Runtime.exec(). But, it is rather difficult to parse the lines returned from ls -l and also not reliable for my purpose of listing the files with accurate details.

So is there any method forcefully set the root folder readable to true by any method?

Comment: `and mounted file system (/) on rw. ` Why? You should have left all unchanged. "/" is already readable and listable on devices below Android N/7.

Comment: yes i could see in emulators of lollipop and marshmallow, the '/' is readable, but what about in higher of N/7. Currently I am testing on Android 10.